# Python 2.7.10 error "from urllib.request import urlopen" no module named request

Tags: python, urllib

I opened python code from `github`.  I assumed it was `python2.x` and got the above error when I tried to run it.  From the reading I've seen Python 3 has depreciated `urllib` itself and replaced it with a number of libraries including `urllib.request`.

It looks like the code was written in python 3 (a confirmation from someone who knows would be appreciated.)
At this point I don't want to move to Python 3 - I haven't researched what it would do to my existing code.

Thinking there should be a `urllib` module for `Python 2`,  I searched Google (using "python2 urllib download") and did not find one. (It might have been hidden in the many answers since `urllib` includes downloading functionality.) I looked in my `Python27/lib` directory and didn't see it there.
Can I get a version of this module that runs on `Python27`?  Where and how?

Answer (score 39):

Try using urllib2:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html

This line should work to replace urlopen:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
```

Tested in Python 2.7 on Macbook Pro

Try posting a link to the git in question.

Comment: This definitely works. You should have to replace urllib.request.urlopen with just urllib2.urlopen

Answer (score 9):

You can program defensively, and do your import as:

```
try:
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    from urllib2 import urlopen
```

and then in the code, just use:

```
data = urlopen(MIRRORS).read(AMOUNT2READ)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
```

Should solve everything

Comment: Yea this works for me, not sure why u got down voted by others

Comment: Still same message here on Heroku: No module named request

Comment: If there is no urllib.request, it's not possible to import its sub-module.

Comment: @rodrigorf Did you ever figure out why Heroku couldn't find requests?

Comment: sorry @Siddhartha, to be honest i don't remember what i did back there, but considering that i no longer have any python apps running on Heroku i guess i gave up trying to figure it out. My jobs are running on Azure today.

Comment: @rodrigorf no worries, thanks for the reply. I ended up moving to an alternate python library called ```requests```, it's almost the same, instead of ```urllib.open(url)```, you do ```requests.get(url).content```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using urllib.request.urlopen()  remove request for python 2.

urllib.urlopen()  you do not have to request in python 2.x  for what you are trying to do. Hope it works for you. 
This was tested using python 2.7  I was receiving the same error message  and this resolved it.

Answer (score 5):

Change

`from urllib.request import urlopen`

to

`from urllib import urlopen`

I was able to solve this problem by changing like this. For `Python2.7` in `macOS10.14`

Answer (score 2):

You are right the *urllib* and *urllib2* packages have been split into *urllib.request* , *urllib.parse* and *urllib.error* packages in Python 3.x. The latter packages do not exist in Python 2.x

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html)  -

> The urllib module has been split into parts and renamed in Python 3 to urllib.request, urllib.parse, and urllib.error.

From [*urllib2* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) -

> The urllib2 module has been split across several modules in Python 3 named urllib.request and urllib.error.

So I am pretty sure the code you downloaded has been written for Python 3.x , since they are using a library that is only present in Python 3.x .

There is a *urllib* package in python, but it does not have the *request* subpackage. Also, lets assume you do lots of work and somehow make *request* subpackage available in Python 2.x .

There is a very very high probability that you will run into more issues, there is lots of incompatibility between Python 2.x and Python 3.x , in the end you would most probably end up rewriting atleast half the code from github (and most probably reading and understanding the complete code from there).

Even then there may be other bugs arising from the fact that some of the implementation details changed between Python 2.x to Python 3.x (As an example - list comprehension got its own namespace in Python 3.x)

You are better off trying to download and use Python 3 , than trying to make code written for Python 3.x compatible with Python 2.x

Comment: Thanks all.  As it turned out it wasn't hard to translate to Python 2.7: just this reference to urllib and a use of it with .decode('utf-8').  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

For now, it seems that I could get over that by adding a `?` after the URL.