# Pagination in Gitlab API only returns 100 per_page max

Tags: curl, gitlab, gitlab-api

I am currently using GitLab API to return all projects within a group. The question I have is, how do I return all projects if there are **over** 100 projects in the group?

The curl command I'm using is `curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: **********" http://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/groups/myGroup/projects?per_page=100&page=1`

I understand that the default page=1 and the max per_page=100 so what do I do if there are over 100 projects? If I set page=2, it just returns all the projects after the first 100.

Comment: You have to iterate until the max count is reached or nothing is returned and then concat the results

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Check the response for the `X-Total-Pages` header. As long as `page` is smaller than `total pages`, you have to call the api again and increment the page variable.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/rest/index.html#pagination-link-header

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for that.