# How to clone all projects of a user in GitLab at once?

Tags: git, gitlab, migration, clone

When I install a new machine I would like to checkout all my personal Git repositories stored at [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/) at once.

I tried some tools like Gitlabber, but they focus on groups. [Group namespaces are not the same as user namespaces](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/) in GitLab. I dont have a group for my projects.

Answer (score 5):

Based on an answer by @dinesh-balasubramanian how to [clone all repositories of a group in GitLab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56679722/3894752) I wrote a command for this.

- Create a [personal access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#creating-a-personal-access-token) with `read_api` scope
- Install `curl` and `jq`
- Run this command to get a list of all projects of a username, search for the SSH URLs of them and execute `git clone` with each result (replace the placeholders before)

  ```sh
  for repo in $(curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXX-YOUR-TOKEN-XXXX" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/XXXX-YOUR-USERNAME-XXXX/projects/?page=1&per_page=100" | jq .[].ssh_url_to_repo | tr -d '"'); do git clone $repo; done;
  ```

  - Note: Gitlab returns a maximum of 100 items per page ([20 items by default](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#offset-based-pagination)) - Change the page value if you have more than 100 projects

Comment: This answer worked for me with a slight tweak where I had to enclose the jq parsing in single quotes. This may help someone else.

for repo in $(curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXX-YOUR-TOKEN-XXXX" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/XXXX-YOUR-USERNAME-XXXX/projects/?page=1&per_page=100" | jq '.[].ssh_url_to_repo' | tr -d '"'); do git clone $repo; done;

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [tool](https://github.com/dejanstefano/clone-me-tender) that I created using python shipped with docker, it will keep the group/subgroup tree structure and will clone/pull all repos that are not mirrored.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31264590)